# List pattern matching for strings with specific StringComparison?

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

I have a case when there is a list of some string. I want to check whether there are exactly 4 items and whether item 0 and item 2 have some value.

But when I write this code...

```cs
var a = new List<string>();
if(a is ["aSdfüü", _, "1.1", _] test){
    // do something
}
```

... it is compiled to this:

```cs
List<string> list = new List<string>();
if (list != null && list.Count == 4 && list[0] == "aSdfüü")
{
    bool flag = list[2] == "1.1";
}
```

So, the strings are compared with "==" and I can't find a way to specify a StringComparison like StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase or similar.

Is there an elegant way to combine list pattern matching and a specific string comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.